# Saving a search to the sidebar in the Ubuntu File Manager

Tags: gnome, filemanager, search

I'd like to setup some saved searches in the sidebar of the Ubuntu File Manager.

- Files modified in the last 3 days
- Files over 30MB

I'm not interested in doing this via the Terminal. After some searching, on Ubuntu 14.04 it appears this could be done by

1. performing the search, then
2. from the `File` menu selecting "Save search as..."

However, I'm using a standard install of Ubuntu 18.04. There is no `File` menu.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not anymore available in recent versions of Nautilus. On the other hand, search is now very much faster and designed to quickly reach a file or folder of interest in you folder structure.

Comment: It didn't seem fast. It hung my Dell XPS 9360 for minutes. When I wanted to list all modified files within my home directory within the last 3 days (which was only 50 files in the end). Plus it was inefficiently trying to search as I was still selecting the search criteria (which was basically just swapping "last opened" to "last modified'.

Comment: You are right. It is slow as soon as you enter any criteria. Plain name search is fast, however, and that is my only use of the search functionailty in nautilus.